# Density of a subset of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

> Consider $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$ where $\{0,1\}$ is a discrete space. Show that the set $A=\{\chi_D \mid D \subset \Bbb R \text{ discrete } \}$ where $\chi_D$ denotes the indicator function is a dense subset of $X$.

I need to show that $A \cap U \ne \emptyset$ for arbitary $U$ open in $X$. This will follow if I can show that $A \cap \left( \prod_{x \in F} U_x \right) \ne \emptyset$ for a basic open set $\prod_{x \in F} U_x$ with $F \subset \Bbb R$ finite.

So let $\chi_S \in X$ and let $U$ be an open set containing $\chi_S$. Then there exists a basic open set $\prod_{x \in F} U_x$ such that $$\chi_S \in \prod_{x \in F} U_x \subset U$$

Now $U_x=\{0,1\}$ for all but finitely many $x \in \Bbb R$. How can I leverage this information to show that the intersection $A \cap \left( \prod_{x \in F} U_x \right)$ is non-empty?

Comment: Hint: A finite set is discrete in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, for any basic open set, we can construct an element that is in this basic open set and in $A$.

Comment: A non-empty open basic subset of $\{0,1\}^\Bbb R$ is a set of the form $\prod_{x \in \Bbb R} U_x$, where $U_x$ is a non-empty subset of $\{0,1\}$ for each $x \in \Bbb R$ and $$F := \{x \in \Bbb R : U_x \neq \{0,1\}\}$$ is a finite set. What happens with $D := \{x \in \Bbb R : U_x = \{1\}\}$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Can you elaborate on what do you mean by constructing an element? I think what I need to do is to take some element in $X$ and a basic open set around it and show that the element is in $A$?

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is this:

Consider any $f \in  X$ and any open neighborhood $U$ of $f$. Then find $\chi_D \in A$ such that $\chi_D \in U$.

If you want, you can write $f = \chi_S$ with a some subset $S \subset  \mathbb R$, but it is not needed in the sequel.

Of course it suffices to consider a basic open $U$ which has the form
$$U = \prod_{x \in \mathbb R} U_x$$
where $U_x = \{0,1\}$ for all but finitely many $x$. Note that $f \in  \prod_{x \in \mathbb R} U_x$ means that $f(x) \in U_x$ for all $x$. In particular all $U_x \ne \emptyset$.

Let $F = \{ x \in \mathbb R \mid U_x = \{1\}\}$ which is a finite, and therefore discrete, subset of $\mathbb R$. Thus $\chi_F \in A$. All $U_x$ with $x \notin F$ contain $0$ (because they are non-empty and $\ne \{1\}$). Therefore $\chi_F  \in U$ because for each $x \in X$ we have $\chi_F(x) \in U_x$: For $x \in F$ we have $\chi(x) = 1 \in U_x$ and for $x \notin F$ we have $\chi_F(x) = 0 \in U_x$.

Comment: $X$ can be expressed as the set $\{\chi_S \mid S \subset \Bbb R\}$ since it consits of maps $f : \Bbb R \to \{0,1\}$. So if I understood you correctly you take an arbitary $\chi_S \in X$ and a neighborhood $U$ for it. Then you consider the basic open set such that $\chi_S \in \prod_{x \in \mathbb R} U_x \subset U$. I am not following the rest of the proof. By definition the set $U_x$ is any open set in $\{0,1\}$ so it can be $\{0,1\}, \{0\}, \{1\}$ or $\emptyset$? It seems that you're only considering the case for when $U_x = \{1\}$?

Comment: @SleepWalker I made a little update and hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thank you. The last bit is still confusing me a bit. You state that for $x \in F$ we have $\chi_F(x) \in U_x$ and for $x \notin F$ we have $\chi_F(x)=0 \in U_x$. Why would $U_x$ contain both $0,1$? There are finitely many $U_x$'s that contain either $1$ or $0$, but not both so I don't see why this would be true?

Comment: Also for $F$ could you have just picked $F = \{ x \in \mathbb R \mid U_x = \{0\}\}$ instead of $F = \{ x \in \mathbb R \mid U_x = \{1\}\}$ or is there something special about $1$?

Comment: @SleepWalker The characteristic functions $\chi_S$ are defined by $\chi_S(x) = 1$ for $x \in S$ and  $\chi_S(x) = 0$ for $x \notin S$.  This explains my definition of $F$. The set $F$ is characterized by $U_x = \{1\}$ iff $x \in F$. There is also a finite set $F'$ with $U_x = \{0\}$ for $x \in F'$. For all other $x$ we have $U_X = \{0,1\}$. Hence for $x \notin F$ we have $\chi_F(x) = 0 \in U_x$. This does not mean that $U_x =\{0,1\}$ for $x \notin F$, only that $0 \in U_x$ for $x \notin F$.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to prove the fact using as much of the reasoning of the OP. The following statements are equivalent:

- the set $A$ is dense,
- $A\cap U\neq\emptyset$ for arbitary $U\neq\emptyset$ open in $X$,
- $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ for arbitary $B\neq\emptyset$ from the base of the topology on $X$.

Let $B$ be a base set. We know that $$B=\prod_{x\in \Bbb R}U_x,\text{ where }\emptyset\neq U_x\subsetneq\{0,1\}\text{ for }x\in F\subset \Bbb R\text{ and }\#F<\infty.$$
Therefore $U_x=\{a_x\}$ for $x\in F$ where $a_x\in\{0,1\}$.
Let $D=\{x\in F:a_x=1\}$. Then $\chi_D\in A\cap B$. This proves the third condition on the density.

Comment: How do you conclude that $\chi_D \in B$? I can see that $\chi_D \in A$ since $D$ is a finite subset of $\Bbb R$ and thus discrete.

Comment: Since for $x\in F$ we have $\chi_D(x)=a_x\in \{a_x\}=U_x$ and for $x\notin F$ we have $\chi_D(x)=0\in\{0,1\}=U_x$.